# convert this conversion function from vb to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, int, type-conversion, tryparse

I have a simple vb method to convert a string to an integer, it is defined like the following:

```
Public Function getInt(input As String) As Integer
    Int32.TryParse(input, getInt)
End Function
```

How can i make it work in `c#` without using an additional integer variable? i can do the same in c# like the following:

```
 public int getInt(string input) 
    {
        int outParam = 0;
        Int32.TryParse(input, out outParam);
        return outParam;
    }
```

Is it possible to avoid the use of extra variable: `int outParam = 0;`

i have tried `Int32.TryParse(input, return);` and `Int32.TryParse(input,out return);` but not working;

**Updates:** The current c# method is working perfectly. am not asking for any alternatives. just wanted to know whether it is possible to customize this method as what i did it in vb(avoid extra declaration of an int variable)

Comment: There's no similar method in `C#` when using `TryParse` as it allows you to easily check if the parse was successful.

Comment: This is only 3 lines of code.  I do not see the issue.  Not everything needs to be a one liner.

Comment: @ sQuir3l: could you please more clear

Comment: @sQuir3l : Not for reduce one line of code, to reduce an extra declaration of a variable.

Comment: Take a look at the referencesource for the implementation of [Int32.TryParse](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,958cb8bc00d00a94) which calls [Number.TryParseInt32](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,958cb8bc00d00a94). Declaring one more variable is very cheap. Did you memory (and/or performance) profile the C# method and found that the additional declaration is a bottleneck, or are you just looking for a mico optimization? To give you a non-answer: no, you cannot avoid `int outparam`, but you can avoid ` = 0`.

Comment: I.e.: `int outparam; Int32TryParse(input out outparam); return outparam;` Btw. you rely on the implementation detail that if `TryParse` fails, `outparam` will be `0`. This behaviour is kind of [guaranteed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7.aspx), but imho goes against the "spirit" of trying to parse a `string` to an `int` (maybe I don't want `0` as a "default" if parsing is impossible). -- much rather had a (built-in) version with a `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: waw.. nice explanation this is enough to accept he comments as answer. thank you Corak

Comment: Finally let me know the reason for the down vote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it is "common knowledge" that declaring a variable is very cheap, which makes this a micro/premature optimization which is generally frowned upon. Also, there are many bad "convert the code" questions. I don't think this is, but maybe someone thought it is "bad by association". Also, it reads a bit like "I know how to do it correctly, but I don't **want** to do it correctly, but still get the correct result."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VB code is using a 'feature' of VB which allows you to use the function name 'getInt' as an implicit local variable.  The last value of this implicit local variable is returned by the function when it exits.

Your C# code is the necessary and correct equivalent - it declares the explicit local 'outParam' to be used in place of the function name and it uses an explicit 'return' in place of VB's implicit return.

The assignment to and returning of the the hidden local variable in VB functions is probably something that should be regarded as a legacy feature that is best avoided since it reduces clarity.

Comment: This is probably the best answer for the "real" question: why can I do this in one line in VB.Net but have to do it in three lines in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Your code above is actually quite good. I don't know why you'd want to do it without the `int` but you could do it like this:

```
public int getInt(string input)
{
    return Int32.Parse(input);
}
```

The problem is it will throw an exception if the string doesn't parse nicely to an integer. The code you provided above is more fault tolerant.

Comment: `Int32.Parse` will throw exception in case of conversion failure

Comment: Correct...as I mentioned in my comment. You could wrap the method with a `try {} catch {}` but then again, it's better just to use `TryParse`.

Comment: Do not use more try catch in your code it will slow down your application performance, use it when ever it is really useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Int32.Parse(input);
```

Or:

```
public int getInt(string input) 
{
    int outParam = 0;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(input, out outParam))
        throw new Exception("Show message!");
    return outParam;
}
```

Comment: Could you have a look at the question please?